# How many process are created by a program that calls fork in a loop with N iterations?

Tags: c, operating-system, fork

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        fork();
    return 0;
}
```

my question:Include the initial parent process, how many processes created by the program?

I think this answer is 1+4=5, 1 parent process and 4 child process. Am I right?

Comment: As [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21273257/fork-number-of-processes-created#comment32054329_21273257) is put on hold as off-topic. This question should be closed too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    fork();
```

This piece of code is equivalant to:

```
fork();
fork();
fork();
fork();
```

Lets say that process start with p0. The process graph will look like:

[image: Process-creation diagram]

The above image says it all, when first fork() gets executed it creates a new process and three fork() are left to execute. Now, here exists a parent thread and a child thread to execute three more  fork() statments. So, child process p1 will create p5,p6 and p7 and parent process will create p2, p3 and p4.
After p2 has been created two more fork() needs to be executed for this child thread p2 which was created after execution of 2nd fork() statment. 
In this way, this parent-child processes are created.

Comment: Wouldn't there also be a p15 as a child of p11? It would have been created with its counter at 2 and still having one more fork to execute, making the total 16 not 15.

Comment: I agree. There should be p15 as a child of p11.
In fact, in general, when you have k calls to fork(), you get a "binomial tree" of order k, Bk. Here we should have the Binomial tree, B4. [Picture of B4](http://cse.iitkgp.ac.in/~abhij/course/lab/Algo1/Autumn11/lab/binotree4.jpg)

Comment: why not p11 has its own another child?

Answer (score 12):

[image: Answer using fork() three times]

The answer using fork() four times is: 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1 = 16 - 1 = 15 processes.

Comment: The image is not the answer to the question

Comment: This isn't correct since it doesn't include the parent process. There should be 16 process created in total. The image answers a different question, if the loop counted to 3 rather than 4.

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a sleep statement to the end of your program like so:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
        fork();
    sleep(10000);
    return 0;
}
```

Next, compile and run your program. Then run `pstree` to see what the process hierarchy looks like.

Answer (score 2):

The first call of fork() will create the first out of 4 children of this parent, and each of the first children will have 3 remaining fork() calls. Which means that each will create 3 children, and the first child of each of those 3 will create 2, and so on.
(What the [highly upvoted answer on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33614018/7733418) left out is the last child on the leftmost leaf.)

[image: 4 fork() calls total creation of processes]

Comment: This is more of a comment on the other answer rather than a standalone answer. Please [edit] to provide an answer to the question, or elaborate on how your image solves the problem. What is incorrect about the other answer? You can comment on that answer when you reach 50 rep. Thanks.

Comment: @Yunnosch Hey, thanks for the feedback. I wanted to add tree representation of process creation like the most recommended one because others were merely giving formula. On top of that, since the most recommended one is giving people wrong answer, I wanted to make it right by using the same representation, thereby people can notice easier what they missed.

Comment: @ggorlen Thanks for the feedback! Just added an extra explanation. I wish I could earn that reputation already and contribute like yall do.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Can you link to the post you're referring to? Most upvoted, or OP selected with the checkmark?

Comment: Both most upvoted and the checkmarked answer have issues.

Comment: "I wanted to add tree representation", which makes yours the third answer to do so. "the most recommended one" is a slightly better phrasing, but please take the [tour] to learn the appropriate terms used on StackOverflow like "upvoted" (and "accepted", which describes the other answer which uses tree representation and has the same issue). Note that, especially once people get the mistake in it, that "most upvoted" is still an unreliable reference to identify a post. Pleaes learn linking via "Share" button beneath posts.

Comment: "I wanted to make it right by using the same representation" but that still is more of a comment, though an impossible one, for lack of pictures in comments. However, your representation (in a subtle way I cannot really define) and your explanation (which I edited for readability, feel free to undo that) together get the 3,2,1,0 countdown better across than the others. I consider that an original valuable insight which your answer provides. I think I kept that and the general "voice" of your post in my otherwise just polishing edit and hope you agree. Have fun.

Comment: I did remove what I perceived an unhelpful stress on "the other one is wrong, nananana", while keeping the matter of fact pointing out of the mistake. with your reputation you cannot comment there and I think this new version is an adequately somber way in the otherwise still valuable answer of yours. I am convinced that it leaves your post in a better light. Feel free to also undo that part, but I recommend that you don't.

Answer (score 0):

its so simple, in this question You just notice that the question said including the initial parent process, so in this case the 2 * 2 * 2 * 2 - 1 is the number of process created and because the question said, including the initial parent, **the answer is 16**.
Goodluck :)

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGc0H.png)

This solution inspired by OS reference books that means the parent process at each level goes to the next branch and the previous branch terminates, because of this we just count leafs.

Answer (score 0):

According to question:
n = 4
Total no. of processes can be created = `2^n`
= `2^4` = `16` .

Answer (score 0):

For the code

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) fork();
```

you can unroll the loop and annotate the steps:

```c
fork(); // 1 process will execute this fork, 2 processes exist afterwards
fork(); // 2 processes will execute this fork, 4 processes exist afterwards
fork(); // 4 processes will execute this fork, 8 processes exist afterwards
fork(); // 8 processes will execute this fork, 16 processes exist afterwards
```

there will be 15 child processes and 1 parent process, 16 total. The process tree looks like:

```
a─┬─b─┬─f─┬─l───p
  │   │   └─m
  │   ├─g───n
  │   └─h
  ├─c─┬─i───o
  │   └─j
  ├─d───k
  └─e
```

The `a` process spawns 4 children: `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`. `b` starts after the first `fork()` and spawns 3 children, `f`, `g`, `h`. `c` starts after the second `fork()` and spawns 2 children. And so on. Each of those children also have `fork()`s in their execution, so they'll spawn more children "recursively".

The issue with OP's attempt is that it doesn't consider branching--that children spawn more children when they hit `fork()`s in their execution.

Existing answers provide solutions of varying degrees of usefulness, but I'd like to add a general strategy to work through these sort of problems on paper (assuming homework/exam scenario, where you can't [run the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20028092/6243352)), regardless of the code structure (there may be branches present and other tricks).

Start with 1 process and begin at its `main()`. Execute the code operation by operation mentally. When you encounter a `fork()` call, make a copy of the code and continue execution on the child process *after* the `fork()` returns. This is hard to keep track of mentally, so you can unroll loops as above, then annotate each fork with the number of children that execute it, taking into account branches and control flow. Writing it down step by step should make it feasible to walk through.

The presence of branches (`if`s) will usually reduce the total number of processes and cannot increase it. If there are no branches, then the total number of processes will be a power of 2, including the original root process.